# How to delete duplicates in a list of lists?

Tags: list, duplicates, wolfram-mathematica

What did I do wrong and what should I do to fix my error in line three?

I'm trying to
Go through each inside list in expsList
Delete any duplicates using DeleteDuplicates and using the Table form of 
Table[expr,{i,{i1,i2.....}}] uses the successive values i1,i2,......

I'm trying to delete duplicates within each individual list of lists and then trying to save the output into a variable named theDeleted. My code seems to work if I type   theDeleted = DeletedDuplicates[expList[[1]]] but not when I make use of the Table command. So what was the reason for the error and how will I be able to fix it (suing the specifics listed above).

```
 n = 3;
  expList = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 365}, 20], {n}];
  theDeleted = DeleteDuplicates[expList[[Table[x, {x, {1, 2, 3}}]]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
theDeleted = Table[DeleteDuplicates[ expList[[x]] ], {x, {1, 2, 3 }} ];
```

Your code creates something that looking at the [Part Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) is of type

> > expr[[{i1,i2,…}]]
> >     gives a list of the parts i1, i2, … of expr.

which just is the original list again.

Eventually you'd want something like

```
Map[ DeleteDuplicates, expList ]
```